# Convert a plist file to text

Tags: ios, plist, converters

This is not a question, but a solution i was puzzled with.

The solution might also help other guys visiting SO having the same problem.

In a iOS game I made I used the plist format to store the level game data.

Now I am into making a level editor for this game, with the purpose to share the game data with close friends or the rest off the world.
It took me a couple of hours to find a solution and i like to share it with you now.

The solution was so simple that i have overlooked a possible solution.

Here it is,
Just open the plist file as a text file and you are good to go, So simple!

See example below, hope this will help some one else.

```
-(NSString *) levelFilePath{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", [path objectAtIndex:0],mm_HomeDirectory,mm_SubDirectory];
    NSString *levelName = [levelnameStr stringByAppendingString:@".plist"];
    return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:levelName];
    NSLog(@"Level-Document %@",levelName);
}

-(void) ReadLevelFileAsText{
    NSString *LevfilePath = [self levelFilePath];
    NSString *textFile;
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:LevfilePath]) {
         textFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:LevfilePath
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:NULL];
    } else {                    
        NSLog(@"filePath does not exists: %@",LevfilePath);
    }
    NSLog(@"Content of File: %@", textFile);   
}
```

Greetings,
J Sneek

Comment: You should post this as a separate question **and** an answer.

Comment: Also, consider storing game data in a different way, your current approach is trivial to hack.

Comment: Hi H2CO3, 
Thank you for your quick answer.
I thought i had a save way of storing game data via MySQL, PHP and JSON connection, can you explain why is it trivial to hack?
The example code i provided is only used for test purposes
Thanks again.

J. Sneek

Comment: Hi H2CO3,
Please forget the question i posted above , i had mixed up two different articels. I understand the securiy issue.